# How-to modify javascript "change font size"?

Tags: javascript, html, font-size

I have such code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeFontSize(element,step)
    { 
     step = parseInt(step,10);
     var el = document.getElementById(element);
     var curFont = parseInt(el.style.fontSize,10);
     el.style.fontSize = (curFont+step) + 'px';
    }
    </script>
```

and such HTML code:

```
    <section id="contentb" style="font-size:16px;">...</section>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeFontSize('contentb',2);">change +</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeFontSize('contentb',-2);">change -</a>
```

How do I write code that I can plus text only to 24px(4 times) and minus only to 8px(4 times)?

Comment: do you mean you don't want the font size to go higher than 24px?

Comment: yes. and what to do that be less only to 8px(4 times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood the question, but if you wan't to limit the fontsize to 24px then this will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeFontSize(element,step)
{ 
 step = parseInt(step,10);
 var el = document.getElementById(element);
 var curFont = parseInt(el.style.fontSize,10);
 if(curFont < 24) {
    el.style.fontSize = (curFont+step) + 'px';
 }
}
</script>

<section id="contentb" style="font-size:8px;">...</section>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeFontSize('contentb',4);">change</a>
```

Comment: And what to do that be less only to 8px(4 times)?

Comment: I updated my post, the font-size is set to 8px at start and if the font-size is less than 24px it will be incremented by 4 on each click at the link.

Comment: it is need to 16px at start! What to do?

Comment: 24px - 16px / 4 = 2px then you should set your font-size to 16px and changeFontSize('contentb', 2); It's very hard to know what you're asking really?

Answer (score 2):

Add `if(curFont >= 24) return;` after defining `curFont`, but before assigning `el.style.fontSize`.